# "I'd the house to myself" Is this incorrect?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, writing

"I'd the house to myself."

Since "I'd" can be a contraction of I had, would it work in this case for "I had the house to myself?"

Comment: So it's more acceptable in British English, but does it apply to past tense too? Most of those examples were in present tense.

Comment: No. The contracted form is for where the word *had* or the whole phrase *I had* is secondary to the context, i.e., the emphasis is elsewhere in the sentence. "I'd **told** him." vs. "I **had** told him." Apparently, the focus in the example sentence is on possessing (having), if I read it correctly.

Comment: I think I'd is a contraction of `I would`

Comment: @ArchieAzares it can be "I had" too - eg "I'd already told him to leave."

Answer (score 2):

It seems incorrect to me.

While "I'd" *seems* to be a contraction for "I had", it's really only valid when "had" is part of a past perfect construction:

- > I'd gone to bed.
- > I'd given him the book.
- > I'd seen enough.

It does not seem appropriate to me as a general contraction for "I had" in any other case.

For more information, see [Past Perfect — The English Club](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verb-tenses_past-perfect_s.htm) (scroll down to "Contraction with Past Perfect").

Comment: I agree, but it would be good to have a reference.

Comment: @Law29: fair. I added a reference, although it's a simple website for teaching English. I am unfamiliar with where to find more scholarly references for such a subject, but I'd be happy to edit again if you can lead me to a better resource.

Comment: It would be better to defer answering until you yourself can provide references. Opinion should be restricted to 'comments'. // The previous answers indicate that the situation is very different  in the UK, where 'I've a new bike I'd like you to see' is standard. Using the contraction _I'd_ where have is a main verb is much rarer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see where you're coming from, and I'll be sure to follow that more closely in the future. However, I do not think this is a duplicate of the other question marked. "I've" is different from "I'd". I've heard "I've" used for possession here in the US too (though less frequently), but I have *never* heard "I'd" as OP was asking.